# Check 4 consecutive identical diagonal elements in 2D Array (Connect 4 game)

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, multidimensional-array

I am working on implementing connect 4 Game on Java. I have almost finished the program that simulates the game.

I use a 2D character array `char [][] board = new char[6][7];` to represent the grid of the game.

I have implemented `checkHorizontal` method to find if there are 4 consecutive identical horizontal elements to check win condition. I have also implemented `checkVertical` method to find if there are 4 consecutive identical vertical elements to check win condition.

I am a little confused in writing algorithm of `checkDiagonal` method that check all possibilities of 4 consecutive identical diagonal elements in 2D array.

Below are 2 examples for diagonal win case on game

case 1:

```
 * * * * * * *
 * * * * * * *
 Y * * * * * *
 R Y * * Y * *
 Y R Y R Y R R
 R Y R Y R Y R
```

case 2:

```
 * * * * * * *
 * * * * * * *
 * * * * * R *
 * * * * R Y *
 * * * R Y R *
 Y Y R Y R Y R
```

How can I check `rows` and `columns` to solve these cases?

Comment: Show us your code and explain what you're stuck on.

Comment: A multi-dimensional array is quite inefficient for this type of thing. A node set that has pointers to all its surrounding grid locations would be better: then you can just follow the node pointers in the direction required.

Comment: it will be more complicated for me if I use node set pointers , I think there is away to check diagonal elements in 2d array

Comment: of course there is a way, but as i said it's inefficient

Comment: @Mohammad: I am embarrassed to ask you to express gratitude and appreciation whenever you get great help here. Chris must have spent an hour or so on his answer customised to your exact requirements, and aside from a clarification question, you gave no thanks at all, nor an upvote. Please take care to respond meaningfully when people donate so much of their time to you.

Comment: @halfer I didn't understand you will this question answered from about 3 month and I accept the answer of Stefan Haustein in my opinion it's the best answer and it solved my problem why you return to this question and put a bounty on it.the problem already solved from 3 months ago.
I really appreciated Chris try to solve my problem but I think Stefan answer is the solution that i need it.
also why the down vote just because i didn't up vote for Chris answer.

Comment: many times I response to questions with very good answers and no one up vote it or appreciate it  but it's not a big matter to me because I do that to help others not for just getting points from them.

Comment: (Intended as friendly and helpful feedback). Thanks for the reply Mohammed. To be clear, you don't have to upvote anyone, and I am not detracting from Stefan's excellent answer. Since politeness is only a social contract that's worthless, you don't have to thank anyone at all if you really don't want to. But flip it on its head: if you helped me for a full hour and I didn't bother to express any thanks to you at all, would I have fulfilled my social obligations? Why would it be such a trouble for me to express my gratitude?

Comment: `why you return to this question and put a bounty on it` - see the bounty reason: "An excellent answer from Chris went unrewarded and unappreciated, and I think it deserves some unicorn points."

Comment: Thanks for clarification halfer and i am sorry for not expressing thanks for Chris answer. put some excuses to me may be I forgot or I got busy and I didn't have time to see his great answer or simply maybe I didn't understand it.

Comment: No worries, and thanks for listening. Have a good day!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You only need to check where a new piece of type `type` has been placed, as the rest of the game field stays the same. There, you can do something like this:

```
/** 
 * Counts pieces of the given type, starting at (y, x), 
 * in the direction denoted by (dy, dx).
 * Stops at field boundaries or when a different field type is encountered. 
 */
int count(char type, int x, int y, int dx, int dy) {
  int count = 0;
  x += dx;  // Skip the piece at (y, x) to avoid counting it twice
  y += dy;  // when looking in both directions on a line.
  while (x >= 0 && x < 7 && y >= 0 && y < 6 && board[x][y] == type) {
    count++;
    x += dx;  // Move in the direction denoted by (dy, dx)
    y += dy;
  }
  return count;
} 

/**
 * Main entry point after a new piece of type `type` was added at (y, x). 
 * Returns true if this connects 4 or more in any direction.
 */
boolean check(char type, int x, int y) {
  return count(type, x, y, -1, 0) + 1 + count(type, x, y, 1, 0) >= 4  // horizontal
      || count(type, x, y, 0, -1) + 1 + count(type, x, y, 0, 1) >= 4  // vertical
      || count(type, x, y, -1, -1) + 1 + count(type, x, y, 1, 1) >= 4  // diagonal
      || count(type, x, y, -1, 1) + 1 + count(type, x, y, 1, -1) >= 4);
}
```

The dx and dy check parameters are used to move in different directions without having a separate method for each direction.

In your horizontal check code, you probably move to the next piece by adding 1 to x in a loop (keeping y constant, i.e. add 0 to y). In your vertical check code, you move to the next piece by adding 1 to y (and 0 to x). To move diagonally, you need to add 1 to both, the x and y coordinates.

To be able to check all directions with a single method, check() uses parameters for the direction of the movement: dx = 1 and dy = 0 adds 1 to x and 0 to y in each step, so you do a horizontal check. With dx = 0 and dy = 1, you do a vertical check.

**Edit**: Got rid of the check helper, as it was only really needed in one place

Comment: Added an explanation at the bottom

Comment: I got it, a lot appreciated

Answer (score 3):

Another solution, less efficient but may be easier to reason with, is to shift the rows by 1 into another array and reuse your vertical win code.

For example, shift the left array for left to right diagonals, into a larger array like this:

```
* * * * * * *    * * * * * * *
* * * * * * *      * * * * * * *
* * * * * R *        * * * * * R *
* * * * R Y *          * * * * R Y *
* * * R Y R *            * * * R Y R *
Y Y R Y R Y R              Y Y R Y R Y R
```

And for right to left diagonals:

```
* * * * * * *                * * * * * * *
* * * * * * *              * * * * * * *
Y * * * * * *            Y * * * * * *
R Y * * Y * *          R Y * * Y * *
Y R Y R Y R R        Y R Y R Y R R
R Y R Y R Y R      R Y R Y R Y R
```

Now you can reuse your vertical win code for diagonal wins.

Comment: in your algorithm I should shift rows in 2 direction of my array to check all cases.

Comment: @MohammadOghli Yes for the two different diagonal types, you need two different shift styles.

Answer (score 2):

Checking the diagonals is akin to checking a horizontal with the added complexity of the array offsets.  One way you can do it is a brute force walk of the array.

You walk with either a row major or a column major. Incrementing your position as you go. Ie below shows a row major walk.

First Check

```
* * * X * * *
* * X * * * *
* X * * * * *
X * * * * * *
* * * * * * *
* * * * * * *
```

Next:

```
* * * * X * *
* * * X * * *
* * X * * * *
* X * * * * *
* * * * * * *
* * * * * * *
```

And so forth.
Once you hit the end of the first row, you increment the row and repeat. 
Ie the first iteration of the next row would be.

```
* * * * * * *
* * * X * * *
* * X * * * *
* X * * * * *
X * * * * * *
* * * * * * *
```

Repeat for all rows and you've covered all the diagonals in that direction. Now repeat for diagonals the opposite direction.

Array wise since you know that your starting from position 4 (index 3), you can simply use direct offsets. Ie

```
if( board[row][column] == board[row+1][column-1] == board[row+2][column-2] == board[row+3][column-3] ){
  /* You have a match */
}
```

Comment: It 's very close to the algorithm that I am thinking about.

Answer (score 0):

A concept I like to use for a lot of grid based problems is called `dx/dy`. The basic idea is you have 2 arrays of numbers, one for delta x and one for delta y, specifying how far to go in that direction. For example: here is a 8 direction dx/dy array pair.

```
int[] dx = {0, 0, 1, 1, 1,-1,-1,-1}
int[] dy = {1,-1, 0, 1,-1, 0, 1,-1}
```

And a smaller, 4 direction array pair:

```
int[] dx = {0, 0, 1,-1}
int[] dy = {1,-1, 0, 0}
```

And a concise version for checking connect 4 since inverse directions are the same for our purposes (i.e Up-Left == Down-Right):

```
int[] dx = {1, 0, 1,-1}
int[] dy = {0,-1, 1, 1}
```

Breaking this down we see can see pretend the stacked numbers are x,y pairs. So if we want 8 directions of movement, consider the board below where `S = (x, y)` of our current position:

```
- - - - - - - -
- - - - - - - -
- - - - - - - -
- - - - S - - -
- - - - - - - -
- - - - - - - -
- - - - - - - -
- - - - - - - -
```

If you look at the `i-th` index of both arrays you will get a pair of dx/dy coordinates (the pairs are vertically aligned in the array above):

```
dx[4] =  1
dy[4] = -1
```

This will give us the delta (or change) in x and y to get to our new position. So looking at the board now you can see where each of the 8 dx/dy pairs would bring you (numbered based on the index of the array):

```
- - - - - - - -
- - - - - - - -
- - - 6 0 3 - -
- - - 5 S 2 - -
- - - 7 1 4 - -
- - - - - - - -
- - - - - - - -
- - - - - - - -
```

So you can see here that position 4 is

`( S.x + 1, S.y - 1 )`

which corresponds to the dx/dy arrays as

`( S.x + dx[4], S.y + dy[4] )`

Now if you were to put that in a for loop you could check all 8 squares around a x,y location.

This concept can be applied many different ways (for example, the knight's movement in chess) by simply constructing different pairs. Consider the arrays for a knight's movement:

```
int[] dx = {1, 1, 2, 2,-1,-1,-2,-2}
int[] dy = {2,-2, 1,-1, 2,-2, 1,-1}
```

And the Grid of the Knight (K) and all his possible moves:

```
- - - - - - - -
- - - - - - - -
- - 4 - 0 - - -
- 7 - - - 2 - -
- - - K - - - -
- 6 - - - 3 - -
- - 5 - 1 - - -
- - - - - - - -
```

---

With this knowledge we can tackle your problem in a few steps.

**Step 1:** Loop over every x,y coordinate in your grid:

```
for(int x = 0; x < width; x++)
    for(int y = 0; y < height; y++)
```

**Step 2:** Now we apply the dx/dy to check all the neighbors in 8 directions:

```
for(int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
        for(int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
        for(int i = 0; i < dx.length; i++) {
            int xTemp = x + dx[i];
            int yTemp = y + dy[i];
        }
    }
}
```

**Step 3:** Check and see if we have any neighbors with the same color:

```
for(int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
        for(int y = 0; y < height; y++) {

        if( GRID(x, y) == EMPTY) continue;

        for(int i = 0; i < dx.length; i++) {
            int xTemp = x + dx[i];
            int yTemp = y + dy[i];

            if( GRID(x, y).color == GRID(xTemp, yTemp).color)
                checkLine( GRID(x, y), dx[i], dy[i], GRID(x,y).color)  
        }
    }
}
```

**Step 4:** `checkLine(Grid, xOrigin, yOrigin, dx, dy)` Now we have to just check in a line to see if we have 4 in a row.

```
boolean checkLine(GRID, x, y, dx, dy, color) {
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) 
        if( GRID(x + dx*i, y + dy*i) != color) return false;

    return true;
}
```

**Step 5:** Finally we need to set the winner. This is just checking what the result of `checkLine()` was.

```
for(int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
        for(int y = 0; y < height; y++) {

        if( GRID(x, y) == EMPTY) continue;

        for(int i = 0; i < dx.length; i++) {
            int xTemp = x + dx[i];
            int yTemp = y + dy[i];

            if( GRID(x, y).color == GRID(xTemp, yTemp).color) {
                if( checkLine( GRID(x, y), dx[i], dy[i], color) ) {
                    winner = color;
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**P.S** For all this psuedo code you will need to handle index out of bounds on your grid. I left that out to reduce clutter.

**P.P.S** I used the `GRID(x, y)` to represent the x,y or row, column pair on the grid. This could easily be replaced with a 2D array. Again this is only psuedo code so I used `GRID(x, y)` for clarity.

Comment: I know this is a bit overwhelming and I tried to keep it short. If you need more clarification feel free to ask! :)

Comment: can you explain to me more how you produce:
 
int[] dx = {0, 0, 1, 1, 1,-1,-1,-1}
int[] dy = {1,-1, 0, 1,-1, 0, 1, -1}

your algorithm more complicated but it would be more effient

Comment: @MohammadOghli check out the top half for more of an explanation

Comment: @MohammadOghli I added a little bit about another application of this concept to help reinforce it.. Hopefully Its not too overwhelming

Comment: If you really want to check the whole board, you don't need to check inverse directions. You can just keep going in one direction and count up, avoiding a search for each possible location. Just keep going from the border of the field and count matching pieces. Reset the counter when you hit a different value (or, in the case of diagonals, overflow)

Comment: @StefanHaustein good point. I'll make a note of that in the answer

Comment: Another great and under-appreciated answer, Chris - excellent work, for which some more unicorn points coming your way.

Comment: Thanks alot Chris for your effort and time.

Comment: @halfer I appreciate you noticing my efforts :) Thanks!