# Chess (Knight) Movement, Avoid Going Off Board

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, chess

I am making a very simple chess program, where it is just movements, no score or anything. I am making the Knight movement, which I am partially done with, but I am stuck on how to avoid the knight going off the board. r = row, c = column, v = the board (8x8)

My Code:

```
public static boolean[][] knightMoves(int r, int c, boolean[][] v){
    if(r <= 7 && c >= 0) v[r+2][c-1] = true;
    if(r <= 7 && c >= 0) v[r+1][c-2] = true;

    if(r <= 7 && c >= 0) v[r+2][c+1] = true;
    if(r <= 7 && c >= 0) v[r+1][c+2] = true;

    if(r <= 7 && c >= 0) v[r-2][c-1] = true;
    if(r <= 7 && c >= 0) v[r-1][c-2] = true;

    if(r <= 7 && c >= 0) v[r-2][c+1] = true;
    if(r <= 7 && c >= 0) v[r-1][c+2] = true;

    return v;
}
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: In your `if` you need to check for valid **destination** points. Also Java arrays are zero-based, so it not clear why you have `> 0` and not `>= 0`.

Comment: yes, i missed that, thank you @PM

Comment: Check out the top half of this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41623648/2341336 It might be useful

Answer (score 0):

This was actually part of a problem in the ACM programming contest years ago.  So the smallest number of lines of code is something like this:

```
boolean check(int r, int c) {
    return r<8 && r>= 0 && c < 8 && c>=0;
}
```

then you could check each potential move from (x,y) to see if it is valid:

```
if check(x+1, y+2) ...
if check(x+2, y+1) ...
if check(x-1, y+2) ...
if (check(x-2, y+1) ...
if check(x+1, y-2) ...
if check(x+2, y-1) ...
if check(x+1, y+2) ...
if (check(x+2, y+1) ...
```

where ... is what you do for a legal move.  if "v" is your board and you start at (x,y) these might be

```
if (check(x+1, y+1))
   v(x+1, y+1) = true;  // indicated knight can move there
```

Comment: This could be further optimized with dx/dy. See the top of this answer for more info :) http://stackoverflow.com/a/41623648/2341336 (the last example in the top half is about a knight in chess)

Comment: You could also simplify this some more by integrating the check and the assignment: `void move(int r, int c, boolean[][] v) { if (r=>0 && r < 8 && c >= 0 && c <= 8) { v[r][c] = true; } }`

Answer (score 0):

The technique I use in my chess engine is to pre-generate all the knight's moves at startup so that all I need to know is which square the knight is on and I can generate all possible knight moves with a single array lookup, e.g.:

```
// Pre-generated knight moves
public static final long[] KNIGHT_MOVES = new long[] {
    0b00000000_00000000_00000000_00000000_00000000_00000010_00000100_00000000L,
    0b00000000_00000000_00000000_00000000_00000000_00000101_00001000_00000000L,
    0b00000000_00000000_00000000_00000000_00000000_00001010_00010001_00000000L,
    // ... etc.
```

So, if my knight is on e4 I simply need KNIGHT_MOVES[4*8+3], and the bit pattern gives me all the moves from that square. It's the fastest way possible which is what you want if you are writing a chess engine.